# How in razor core to create a link that has all current parameters plus some more

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm on a page `SomePage?A=a&B=b&...`

I want to construct a URL that has all of the current `GET` parameters plus some more from an `IDictionary<string, string>` that I have.

The tag helper `asp-all-route-data="@myDictionary"` will get set the parameters from my dictionary, but I don't understand:

1. how to create a link with all of the current parameters; or
2. how to add extra parameters to such a link.

Comment: Could one make a tag helper to be called something like `asp-existing-route-data-and="@myDictionary"`?

Answer (score 0):

Well this works, but I think it's a bit crap because:

- this feels like a really obvious thing to want to so so I don't believe that there isn't an *out of the box* way to do it,
- I can't get the extension method to work -- it has to be called as `MakeGet(this, d)` rather than just `MakeGet(d)`, and
- Shouldn't we be using something like a `NameValueCollection` that models multiple keys as are supported in `GET`?

```
        public static IDictionary<string, string> MakeGet<T>(this RazorPage p, IDictionary<string, T> d)
        {
            return MakeGet(p, d.ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => { try { return z.ToString(); } catch { return null; } }));
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, string> MakeGet(this RazorPage p, IDictionary<string, string> d)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string k in d.Keys)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d[k]))
                {
                    result.Add(k, d[k]);
                }
            }

            IQueryCollection get = p.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> q in p.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query)
            {
                if (!result.Keys.Contains(q.Key))
                {
                    result.Add(q.Key, string.Join(",", q.Value));
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The *next* problem is how to subsequently remove a parameter in the controller in order to do a redirect.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableDeleteAsync()
        {
            // Need to remove parameter LineNumber.
            return RedirectToAction("Get");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I've come up with for the parameter removal.

```
        public static RouteValueDictionary QueryWithout(this PageModel p, params string[] remove)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary q = new RouteValueDictionary();
            foreach (var kv in (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(p.Request.QueryString.Value).Where(z => !remove.Contains(z.Key))))
            {
                q.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
            return q;
        }
```

Being used like this

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableDeleteAsync(int lineNumber)
        {
            ImportStagingRecord i = _context.ImportStagingRecords.Find(FileId, lineNumber);
            if( i != null)
            {
                _context.ImportStagingRecords.Remove(i);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary q = BaseUri.QueryWithout(this, "LineNumber", "handler");
            return RedirectToAction("", q);
        }
```

Again, I think it's crap.

(The query string contains lots of parameters for sorting, filtering, and paging the table of `ImportStagingRecord`s which need to be preserved across requests.)